# problema ao instalar o Django

Tags: django

Baixei o *Django* e descompactei na área de trabalho fui ate o *Cmd* digitei ***cd desktop*** logo em seguida ***cd Django-1.6.2*** que é o nome da pasta do *Django* até aqui tudo bem, mais quando executo o código ***python setup.py install*** para fazer a instalação dele aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> 'python' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
>   ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.

Oque devo fazer ?

Comment: Cara, o django 1.6 já é bem ultrapassado, trabalhe com o django 1.8 ou 1.9. Pode tentar a nível de aprendizado mas várias coisas dele já são obsoletas.

Answer (score 4):

Primeiro você precisa instalar o *Python*.

Baixe ele no [site oficial](https://python.org/downloads/). Quando for instalar marque a opção **Add Python 3.5 to PATH** e instala.

Depois de instalar o *Python* dessa forma ele vai estar listado no *PATH* do *Windows* como comando e esse erro vai parar.

Depois disso eu aconselho a usar o *Virtualenv*, ele é para você criar um ambiente separado para cada projeto.

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
```

Depois instalar você cria um *Virtualenv* para o seu projeto:

```
mkvirtualenv nomedoseuprojeto
```

Após isso manda trabalhar com o seu *Virtualenv* criado:

```
workon nomedoseuprojeto
```

Agora manda instalar o *Django* assim:

```
pip install django
```

Ele vai instalar o *Django* no seu *Virtualenv*.

[Guia para instalação no Windows](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/windows/)

Comment: Obrigado ricardo dica valiosa !

Comment: Se respondeu sua pergunta não deixe de marcar como resposta, isso ajuda a outras pessoas e fecha o post.